# Ember dynamic navigation bar

Tags: ember.js, navigation, nav

I'm trying to build a dynamic navigation bar in Ember. It ought to be pretty straightforward, but I'm having a hell of a time getting it to work.

I tried to replicate what Spiegel does here: http://spiegela.com/2014/05/28/writing-a-navigation-bar-controller-in-ember-js/

JSBin link to what I have so far: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yoqab/3/edit

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution, for any who have the same problem: http://jsbin.com/yoqab/7/edit